# Can't execute a script on a mounted external drive

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

The /mnt/ext is mounted to an ext2 filesystem, an external hard drive. For some reason I can't run scripts from there. Please see the session below.

```
luntain@plato /mnt/ext $ echo "echo success" > k.sh
luntain@plato /mnt/ext $ chmod 777 k.sh
luntain@plato /mnt/ext $ ./k.sh
-bash: ./k.sh: Permission denied
126luntain@plato /mnt/ext $ ll k.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 luntain luntain 13 Jan 23 15:08 k.sh*
luntain@plato /mnt/ext $
```

I would love to find out why I see the error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably there was a `noexec` attribute set when the filesystem was mounted; maybe it is your distribution 'feature'.

To check it you can execute `mount` that will show mount options in parentheses, and to remove `noexec` flag you can use `mount -o remount,exec /mnt/ext` under root.

Also, make sure you place the exec option after the user option, or the system will still mount your drive as noexec.

Comment: This [post is helpful](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37980/partition-mounted-noexec-even-though-not-specified-in-etc-fstab) in case you are puzzled by why `noexec` is there even though it is not in the `fstab`.

Answer (score 3):

The file system is mounted with the noexec option.

Answer (score 3):

A filesystem mounted `noexec` only prevents executing the script (i.e., asking the kernel to execute it appropriately based on a magic number or a shebang line). It doesn't prevent you from calling an interpreter on another filesystem mounted `exec` and passing the script as an argument (or on stdin) to said interpreter. Ergo, if not root, you could have worked around this with just `sh k.sh`.