# How to execute a program from ENCFS encrypted file system

Tags: linux, permissions, encryption

I created an encrypted file system using ENCFS.  Everything works as expected, except executing programs in the FS. The permissions on both the unecrypted and encrypted FS directories are "drwxrwxrwx.".

When I try to execute a trivial bash script or executable, I get the following:

```
$ ./hello.sh
bash: ./hello.sh: Permission denied
$ ./hello
bash: ./hello: Permission denied
```

The files are readable:

```
$ sh ./hello.sh
hello
```

File permissions are correct:

```
rwxrwxr-x. 1 eager eager 18K Jan  8 10:04 hello*
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 eager eager  25 Jan  8 09:58 hello.sh*
```

Why am I getting "Permission denied" and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The permissions on the directory do not matter. Rather, the file permissions are the deciding part. What are the file permissions?

Comment: Oops, should have included that as well.  Permissions on both are "-rwxrwxr-x.".

Comment: `should have included that as well` – Then please [edit] the question and include that.

Comment: What does `mount` say about the filesystem? Is [`noexec`](https://superuser.com/a/99637/432690) there?

Comment: Mount says "noexec", which answers the initial question.  Is there any way to get fuse/ENCFS to mount with "exec"?

Answer (score 0):

The default mount options for fuse (apparently) include "noexec".  man mount.fuse(8) only mentions "nodev,nosuid" being set by default.  The man page says that other standard mount options are supported.

Changing the fstab entry to the following worked:

```
encfs#/fs/encrypt /fs/unencrypt fuse rw,user,exec,noauto    0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to use

```
encfs -o umask=077 "/media/user/USBFLASH/" /home/user/mountdir
```

because my encrypted folder was located on a NTFS-formatted USB stick and encfs/fuse/whatever underlying file system responsible for actual storing the file permissions ignored all attempts to set any permissions.

Also remember about `encfs --no-default-flags` while dealing with `-o fuse_option` because encfs can override your flags by default.