# ./configure Permission denied at /home dir after migration on aarch64

Tags: bash, permissions, arch-linux

I copied with "cp -a" the /home from my old x86_64 ArchLinux workstation to new ArchLinux on VIM3 PRO SBC Khadas.
I am trying to compile wanting packages which absent in aarch64 repositories.

And when I ./configure script launch bash exits with error:

```
leha@VIM3 ~/aarch_packages/gphotofs/src/gphotofs-0.5 :( $ LC_ALL=C; ./configure
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

But ./configure script belongs current user

```
leha@VIM3 ~/aarch_packages/gphotofs/src/gphotofs-0.5 $ LC_ALL=C ls -l configure
-rwxr-xr-x 1 leha leha 430534 Jul 10  2012 configure
```

and current directory also belongs current user

```
leha@VIM3 ~/aarch_packages/gphotofs/src/gphotofs-0.5 $ LC_ALL=C ls -l ..     
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 leha leha 4096 Dec 17 08:54 gphotofs-0.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 leha leha   55 Dec 17 08:54 gphotofs-0.5.tar.bz2 -> /home/leha/aarch_packages/gphotofs/gphotofs-0.5.tar.bz2
```

UID, GID and name of this user on x86 and on aarch64 machines also matchs up.

```
leha@VIM3 ~/aarch_packages/gphotofs/src/gphotofs-0.5 $ LC_ALL=C ls -ln configure
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 430534 Jul 10  2012 configure
leha@VIM3 ~/aarch_packages/gphotofs/src/gphotofs-0.5 $ LC_ALL=C id           
uid=1000(leha) gid=1000(leha) groups=1000(leha),5(tty),8(mem),11(ftp),33(http),969(mysql),985(video),986(uucp),991(lp),995(audio),997(kmem),998(wheel)
```

And all is completely working if I build package outside own home dir, for example in /Arch/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute a script on a mounted external drive](https://superuser.com/q/99635/432690). To respond, you may need this: [How to get mount point of filesystem containing given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90252/108618).

Comment: Yes. Very big thanks!))