# Cannot execute bash script even though +x exists

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes

I'm having trouble getting a gitlab-runner to execute tasks and not sure what I am doing wrong. This is running in Kubernetes but probably not related to Docker or Kubernetes or anything else.

```
/bin/bash: line 1: /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script: Permission denied
```

Executing into the actual pod:

```
runner-qeaugn8yj-project-1002-concurrent-0-m5ikq7m3:/# ps -auxwww
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root          1  0.0  0.0   2416  1784 ?        Ss   10:21   0:00 /bin/bash
root         15  0.0  0.0   2740  2464 pts/0    Ss   10:50   0:00 bash
root         21  0.0  0.0   1740   788 pts/0    R+   10:50   0:00 ps -auxwww

runner-qeaugn8yj-project-1002-concurrent-0-m5ikq7m3:/# ls -lahtr /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root         434 Oct  4 10:21 /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script

runner-qeaugn8yj-project-1002-concurrent-0-m5ikq7m3:/# /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script
bash: /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script: Permission denied

runner-qeaugn8yj-project-1002-concurrent-0-m5ikq7m3:/# bash /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script
{"script": "/scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script"}
Running on runner-qeaugn8yj-project-1002-concurrent-0-m5ikq7m3 via gitlab-runner-7b66fddb55-tr6b5...
{"command_exit_code": 0, "script": "/scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script"}
```

The script is running as root and so is my output from above.

```
runner-qeaugn8yj-project-1002-concurrent-0-m5ikq7m3:/# cat /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

start_json="{\"script\": \"$0\"}"
echo "$start_json"

...
```

Comment: In general such problem may be caused by [`noexec` option given to `mount`](https://superuser.com/a/99637/432690). I don't know Kubernetes at all, so I cannot tell if (how, why) this is possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes system security prevents scripts from running is certain directories. To get around this, you can try running the script in a different location or type bash before the script name. This invokes a sub shell with different file permissions.

```
bash /scripts-1002-1043121/prepare_script
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, as shown above, but I don't know why the original script fails, which I have no control over. If there's a chmod or chown that I can run, I can gladly try that.

Comment: @brainwash The chmod command will help you because your permission is already at 777.  This means the script is already executable.
This is the command: ```chmod +x```